# Dockerfile for nodejs on Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I am newbie on Kubernetes. I have this dockerfile and deployed on kubernetes but it crash every 50s. What is wrong am I doing ?

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.14

RUN apk add dumb-init

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY --chown=node:node . .
RUN npm ci --only=production
USER node

EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "dumb-init", "node", "server.js" ]
```

Comment: Use `kubectl logs <pod-name>` to get why it crash.

Comment:  Server ready at http://0.0.0.0:4000/graphql 
after that it stopped.

Comment: Could it be a memory resource problem. Have you added resource memory limit? `kubectl get <pod-name> -o yaml` should get the problem at the end

Comment: Please add your Pod/Deployment yaml, and the output of `kubectl logs <pod-name>` to your question. You can do this by editing your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem has been solved. It was kuberntes server problem that it doesn't have sufficient memory.

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. Please post a solution as an answer, even if it's trivial, or a workaround, so the question won't stay unanswered.